Calculating the amplitude of a vibration based on the sound intensity
I am stuck on this problem.
Assume I have a speaker generating a single frequency tone, $f_s = 100$ Hz, and I want to calculate the amplitude of the speaker vibration $A_s$. I measure the sound intensity, $I$, to 60dB at 1m from the speaker.
I've tried the formula: $I = \frac{a^2 v \rho (2\pi f_s)^2}{2}$ where $v = 343$ m/s is the of sound in air, $\rho = 1.29 $ kg/m^3 is the density of air, and $a$ is the amplitude of the sound wave at this point in space.
But I don't know of to connect the value of $a$ 1m away form the speaker to the value of $A_s$.
I am also assuming that the values of $A_s$ and $a$ at the speaker must be the same, but I can not find any support for or against that assumption.
